# Erorr accessing GreaseMonkey sandbox API

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Yup, it's basically the same old question. Writing my first GreaseMonkey script, script tells me that GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined. Upon further investigation - I don't think I have access to the API in general, GM_info gives me the same problem.

Here's the full script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Mirror Page
// @namespace   mailto:linkhyrule5@gmail.com
// @description POSTs page to dynamic page mirror
// @include     http://www.google.com
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM_info
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(GM_info);
var ihtml = document.body.innerHTML;
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
 method:'POST',
 url:'http://localhost:5723/index.php',
 data:"PageContents=" + escape(ihtml) + "\nURL=" + escape(document.URL),
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

on the Google homepage gets me

```
/*
Exception: ReferenceError: GM_info is not defined
@Scratchpad/1:11:1
*/
```

and, earlier, `GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined`.

Running GreaseMonkey 3.7 on Firefox 45.0. I've rebooted Firefox and enabled/disabled; the script exists purely in my clipboard and sandbox, but insofar as "removing the script and recreating it from clipboard" counts I've also reinstalled the script.

I've now tried copying the file into a .user.js file and installing from there; still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Reload and Run option in the scratchpad does not work with any script that requires the Greasemonkey sandbox, as discovered [here](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1771).